# How to filter product list by custom attribute on category page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, filter, custom-attributes

I want to list product by my custom attribute so how can i filter this without changing vendor>magento files.

I am displaying my attribute in header. when it changes its filter by my custom attribute.

How can i do this?